# GData & Google plus conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus, gdata

Hello iOS Development gurus! I hope your code would work out clean and smooth!

I need your help!

I need my app to be able to share through the gmail and google+. So I use two libraries for that: Google plus framework package (GoogleOpenSource.framework, GooglePlus.bundle & GooglePlus.framework) and Gdata library (libGDataTouchStaticLib.a) + headers.

Both libraries are working out for me fine while I use them in separate projects, but when I add them to one project as I need now and build it for the device (if simulator it is still ok) I get the following error: .

> *105 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7*

So as I understand 105 ivars in the following classes are getting duplicated in the project: `GTMHTTPFetcher`, `GTMHTTPFetcherService`, `GTMHTTPFetchHistory`.

Can anyone help me to avoid this problem?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, have you got any solution for this?

Comment: A workaround is to use the Gdata library and create custom g+ login class. It was easy as the app did not have the sharing feature but log in only. As for the both libraries they are just conflicting and I could not find the way to fix it and had to chose which one I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the way to get them working together, so I've found out a workaround here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-20-protocol--mobile-18394

and here

[Not able to get access token for google+ through Oauth 2.0 in iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933829/not-able-to-get-access-token-for-google-through-oauth-2-0-in-iphone-application)